# yii cannot hide entry url

Tags: php, yii

I wish to let

```
http://localhost/demo/index.php?r=greeting
```

to access via

```
http://localhost/demo/greeting
```

in config/main.php, i set to

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,      
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

and I put the following  to .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

I can get

```
http://localhost/demo/index.php/greeting
```

working but not

```
http://localhost/demo/greeting
```

works what is the reason?

Comment: `http://localhost/demo/greeting` don't match any of your url rules. What is the default action for your `greeting` controller ?

Comment: You have conditional rewrite with `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`, you sure rewrite module is loaded? What does it mean *not working*, apache error, or yii error?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
),
        'showScriptName'=>false,
    ),
```

for the htaccess part

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#otherwise forward to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Looks like yours, but you have to make sure the .htaccess file is outside the protected folder, thus inside the root folder of your web directory.

Answer (score -1):

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                    'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
                            'gii'=>'gii',
                            'gii/<controller:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
                            'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',

            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<key:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>/<param:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

Try this one. Its work for me. Also this include part for gii url . Using this you also can open your gii panel using following url `http://localhost/demo/gii`

Also in what .htaccess you have made this changes ?